# Multiple references to abstract class in the same line

Tags: c++, abstract-class, c++23

I have the following code:

```
class Agent {
public:
    Agent();
    int foo=5;
protected:
    virtual int Calculate() = 0;
};

class Game {
public:
    Game();
    Agent& agent0, agent1;
};
```

This code fails to compile with the error:

```
error: cannot declare field ‘Game::agent1’ to be of abstract type ‘Agent’
```

However, when you split the line `Agent& agent0, agent1;` into two lines:

```
Agent& agent0;
Agent& agent1;
```

it compiles fine. Why is this happening? I thought there should be no difference between the two.

Comment: What type do you think `agent1` is when declared via `Agent& agent0, agent1;`?

Comment: as the error message says, what you wrote declares `agent1` to be a `Agent`, not an `Agent&`. Common recommendation is to declare 1 variable per line

Comment: The confusion you face is exactly the reason for the recommendation to declare one variable per line as mentioned above (especially where pointers/references are involved).

Comment: fwiw, once you fixed that, the next error is that you cannot leave the references uninitialzed. Reference members are usually not a good idea. Consider if you rather want pointers

Comment: its a quirk in the grammar that causes this. I suggest to never declare >1 variable per line, and then you can still debate whether it should be `Agent& agent0;` or `Agent &agent0;`, I have seen ppl argue in favor for both, but I see clear preference of the former (which doesnt work with >1 per line)

Comment: Just do this: `template <typename T> using type = T;` and then you can do `type<Agent&> agent0, agent1;`.  It is the same workaround technique for the limitation of function-like C casts cannot have multiple words, `bar = type<unsigned long long>(foo);`  (Although that will work... seriously, just declare 1 variable per line.)

Comment: @Eljay nice one. I like c++ because it invites to be creative :D